# Find the flux of the vector field across the closed surface of the three-dimensional region E

Tags: calculus

Let E be the part of the ball $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1$ with $z \geq 0$. Find the flux of the vector field $F=2x^2y \hat{i} +2yz \hat{j}-z^2 \hat{k}$ across the closed surface of the three-dimensional region E.

Can someone tell me the setup of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since the surface is closed, divergence theorem may be used. The divergence of $F$ is equal to $4xy+2z-2z = 4xy$. The integral of the divergence over $E$ can be conveniently expressed in   cylindrical coordinates... but maybe it's better to notice that the region is symmetric with respect to $x\mapsto -x$ reflection, which changes the sign of the integrand. Consequently, the integral is zero.